# Command Dispatch pattern iOS and alternatives with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, networking, afnetworking

I’m trying to find the best patterns for handling network exceptions, authorization needed notifications and so on.

I’ve tried to implement the example in Chapter 5 of this book: Professional iOS Network Programming: Connecting the Enterprise to the iPhone and iPad. The complete code for the example can be downloaded from this page:

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-iOS-Network-Programming-Connecting-the-Enterprise-to-the-iPhone-and-iPad.productCd-1118362403,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

The pattern used in this example is Command Dispatch, which seems pretty cool, for handling and delegating responsibility. The effect of this should be global networking error handling and login needed handling.

Unfortunately this example is created for iOS5, and use the NSURLConnection synchronous calls, and not the really nice looking AFNetworking asyncronous.

What i’m asking for is best practices for handling network reachability issues, network errors, login authorization and so on. Is there a way to do something similar to the Command Dispatch pattern using AFNetworking ?

A little side note is that i’m trying to connect my application to a rails api, using HTTP Digest approach. So a related question would be handling server authentication challenges, and storing the tokens on the device.